# JavaScript - Get current focused element that hasClass() with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is just a simple question for you but here I'm having a hard time trying to solve my own problem.

In my case, I have several text field that changes color of the field's border and label's text when the field itself is focused, and will revert changes when it is not focused. So then I used the following code: (see my [demo](http://jsbin.com/rihogopupu/edit?html))

```
$(function() {
  $(".field").focus(function() { /* ... */ });
  $(".field").blur(function() { /* ... */ });
});
```

But since I'm pointing to the class `.field`, all elements that have this class will be affected so I thought I have to set the current active element with the class `.field` so the other elements will be excluded. I used the below code but it doesn't work (and I don't even know if I'm right about the idea):

```
var current = $(document.activeElement).hasClass(".field");
$(current).focus(function() { /* ... */ });
$(current).blur(function() { /* ... */ });
```

If there's another way to settle this please tell me how.

Hope you could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: remove css or add class to elements on focus of an element except current one, you can achieve this with `:not`, `$('.field').not(current).addClass...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your $(".field") selector to $(this) to select the field and $(this).next() to select the field's label inside both your blur and focus functions. *Only* the selected field and the next label will be selected, see this snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".field").focus(function() {
    /* when field with or without value is focused, add these classes */
    if ($(this).val().length || $(".field").val().length == "") {
      $(this).addClass("field-is-focused");
      $(this).next().addClass("label-is-focused");
    }
  });
  $(".field").blur(function() {
    /* when field with or without value is not focused, remove added classes */
    if ($(this).val().length || $(".field").val().length == "") {
      $(this).removeClass("field-is-focused");
       $(this).next().removeClass("label-is-focused");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.label {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.field {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.field:focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

/*---------------------------------*/

.field-is-focused {
  border-color: blue;
}
.label-is-focused {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
 <title>jQuery - Get current focused element</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <form>
   <fieldset>
  <!-- input email type field -->
  <input type="email" class="field">
  <label class="label">Email</label>

  <!-- input password type field -->
  <input type="password" class="field">
  <label class="label">Password</label>
  
  <!-- textarea field -->
  <textarea class="field"></textarea>
  <label class="label">Comment</label>
   </fieldset>
 </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will not change the label color

Comment: @edisoni.1337 Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated my snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the focus CSS propert for the class .field.

```
.field :focus{
/*your style change*/
}
```

This might eliminate the focus/blur event functions.Hope this helps!

Comment: But due to HTML5 validation, I have to use JS to deal with it.